# Excel Power Query Editor: Reformat the text in each individual box of a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, python, power-query

I currently converted a list of roughly 1200 items (1200 rows) and a problem arose when I looked at the date of each individual item and realised that the day and month was before the year which meant that ordering them by date would be useless. Is there any way I can reorder over 1200 dates so that they can be formatted correctly with me having to manually do it. Would I have to use python? I am very new to that and I don't know how to use it really.

Here's an example of what I have: September 9 2016

And this is what I want: 2016 September 9

I am also using the Microsoft excel if anyone was asking. I took the table from Wikipedia and the column there had it formatted correctly and could sort the data properly. Would I

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Please edit your post and include a screenshot of your data and the wikipedia link where you got the data from.

Answer (score 0):

Good Day,

What I would do is add a column to convert the text date into a numeric date.  You can then copy and paste these values over your originals. The date formula works well for this =DATE(Year,Month,Day)

Assuming the dates are in column A.

So since the year is first in the formula but last in your data use Right to strip this out taking 4 digits.
=(RIGHT(A1,4)

With month being first use the month Left formula to get the first 3 letters of the month and plug them into the MONTH formula.
MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3)

The date is a bit more complicated, but use the FIND formula to find the first space or " ", then add 1 to this figure and take two digits
MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2)

Combine it for =DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),(MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3))),MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2))

And you should be in good shape.

[image]

Then it is just a matter of applying the format you want.

[image]

Hopefully, this helps.